# grails - handling 'mostly' static content

Tags: grails, static-content

What would be the recommended way to handle mostly static content in grails app like 'about us' 'terms and cond.' type of pages. Would need to be editable, however would mostly stay the same for very long stretches of time. keep those things in text files read in only for editing? I'm trying to keep it as simple and light.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think storing raw content outside the WAR or DB is a idea, normally.  It usually ends up being a security risk, and also coupling your application too closely to the underlying system.

You could store the editable content in a database or NoSQL like normal, but implement good caching. For example, [this plugin does template caching](http://grails.org/plugin/template-cache), so the templates won't actually be generated as long as they are in memory.

Another option (I have not used) is a full-blown CMS for Grails, like [Weceem](http://www.weceem.org/weceem/).  Depending on how much editing capabilities you need, this could be overkill or save a ton of time.

Comment: ... the potential for security risk worried me the most.